# How to Exporting Charts As Images on fusion charts?

Tags: php, fusioncharts

I am trying to convert my chart as a jpg. i am getting option save as jpeg, png, pdf. But the problem is after selecting options (like jpeg etc) i am getting a new window "http://localhost/Dashboard9/FusionCharts/FCExporter.php" with

DOMId=height=0width=0fileName=statusMessage= Export Resource not found.statusCode=0

I have placed FCExporter.php at "http://localhost/Dashboard9/FusionCharts" . My internet connection is on while doing this.

Using code like

```
<graph caption='Average Score' subcaption='$myCaption' divlinecolor='F47E10' numdivlines='3' showAreaBorder='1' areaBorderColor='000000' numberPrefix='' showNames='1' numVDivLines='29' vDivLineAlpha='30' yAxisName='Average Score' formatNumberScale='1' rotateNames='1' decimals='1' decimalPrecision='1' exportEnabled='1' 
exportHandler='http://localhost/Dashboard9/FusionCharts/FCExporter.php' exportAtClient='0' exportAction='download' exportTargetWindow='_blank' exportFileName='MyFileName'>
```

Nothing was changed on FCExporter.php
what is the problem, i am not getting. Any Help?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you missed copying the `Resource` folder that resides along with `FCExporter.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Change `SAVE_PATH & HTTP_URI` in FCExporter.php file

example:

```
define ( "SAVE_PATH",  "/opt/lampp/htdocs/dashboard/temp" );
define ( "HTTP_URI", "http://dasboard.co.id/temp/" );
```